# Merge non-grouping elements in column using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible to group rows with columns and have the remaining data merged in another column ?

Here's an image to better understand the question and see what I want to achieve:

[The wanted result http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/9227/linqgroupingquestion.gif](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/9227/linqgroupingquestion.gif)

You can see the grouping by `IdPlace`, `IdInternship` and the new column `IdUsers` made with details, or composition of user ids.

I don't care if I cannot work anymore with data in new column, it's for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like:

```
var result = 
  collection.GroupBy(x => new { x.IdPlace, x.IdInternship })
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.IdPlace, x.Key.IdInternship,
           IdUsers = String.Join(", ", 
                        x.Select(c => c.IdUser.ToString()).ToArray()) });
```

(`.ToArray()` is unnecessary in .NET 4.0)